# preserve whitespace characters in textarea white editing in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, whitespace

I got an issue with whitespace in my textarea.
A text with a few paragraphs gets saved to the database with all the \r\n inside.

But when I try to put the same again into a textarea to edit the text all that nice whitespace stuff goes down the drain.

I got a js to add the values
    $("#instruction_textarea").val("<%= @text %>")
but I don't know how to keep my text with its formatting(whitespace only nothing more). simple_format does not do the trick as I don't need p tags inside the textarea.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. The .val function is responsible for stripping all whitespace information off. I worked around it by putting the data in through a template parameter earlier. I had to fetch the data from the database even if it already was in the site. It does not really matter but it still the less efficient solution.